# Creating Layer for Selected Features, then Moving it using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, editing, select

I have a problem with ArcGis 10.1 which I rarely use.

In an edit session I select a polygon. I would like to 'Create Layer for Selected Features' and can do this; the new layer appears in the table of contents. When I try and move the new layer, the old layer moves with it.

When I click on the polygon the option of selecting the two coincident polygons appears but I can't get these to separate. It seems to be impossible to do anything to one feature and not the other.

The strange thing is that yesterday the program wasn't behaving like this.

Can anyone can explain what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A layer is just a *view* of data - not the data itself. When you create a layer from a selection, you're just making another view of the same data. So if you edit *the data*, then *both* views are going to change.

If you want two independent features, you need to actually copy the data - either via copy in an edit session which just duplicates the feature in that dataset, or by exporting your selection which creates an entirely new dataset out of your selection.